# Exchange Web Services?

Tags: soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007, exchange-server-2010

does Exchange Server 2007 and 2010 allows us to create Appointment, Emails, Contacts through EWS (Exchange Web Service)?

I'm truing using SoapUI to test that and I keep getting

> HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed Allow:
>
> GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE Server:
>
> Microsoft-IIS/7.0 X-Powered-By:
>
> ASP.NET Date: Tue, 16 Nov 2010
>
> 14:05:48 GMT Content-Length: 0

any suggestions?

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To which URL are you pointing SoapUI?

https://servername/EWS/Exchange.asmx would be the correct one.

Replace servername with the DNS name of your Exchange box.